# Ошибка в написании кода на С

Tags: c, visual-studio, codeblocks

Задача: дан массив 4n целых чисел. Используя дополнительный вектор размером n, совершить преобразование массива по схеме. Должно выдавать изначальную матрицу, а потом измененную. У меня не совпадают их элементы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int n, i;

   printf("Enter N\n\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   int A[4*n], B[n];
   printf("\t\tVector A\n\n");
   for(i=0; i<4*n; i++){
    A[i]=rand()%10;
   printf("%d ", A[i]);}

   for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    B[i]=A[n-1-i];
    A[i]=B[i];
    B[i]=A[n+i];
    A[n+i]=A[3*n+i];
    A[3*n+i]=B[i];
    B[i]=A[3*n-1-i];
    A[2*n]=B[i];
   }
   printf("\n");
   for (i=0; i<4*n; i++){
    printf("%d ", A[i]);}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `B[i]=A[n-1-i];
    A[i]=B[i];` и тут вы уже затёрли `A[i]`. ошибка в логике.

Comment: так мне так и надо, первую часть нужно просто развернуть. я ее разворачиваю, перенося в В, а потом обратно в А

Comment: ещё раз. В какой переменной после первых 2 строчек цикла находится значение которое было в `A[i]`? Первые 2 строки можно записать так `A[i] = A[n-1-i]` `B[i]` вы затрёте следующей строкой.